# Unable to flag as duplicate

Tags: discussion, support, exact-duplicates

[Help updating my Test Class for a trigger I created](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135733/help-updating-my-test-class-for-a-trigger-i-created) just showed up in the new users reveiw quene, and looks to be a near exact dupliate of [Test class not covering line in trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135723/test-class-not-covering-line-in-trigger), asked earlier today, with an unsatisfying answer.

However, I'm unable to flag it as a duplicate due to the duplicate question not having an accepted or upvoted answer.

Additionally, it seems to me that the user who asked the first question, created a new account, and asked the same question again. Hopefully the upvote on the second question isnt from the first account.

What should I do here? Just leave a comment and move on? Upvote the duplicates answer just to flag the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to have been resolved. Posting here is fine, or you should be able to flag them with a comment so moderators can review.

Comment: That was me, I upvoted one of the questions answers and flagged the other one as a duplicate. I wanted to ask here first, since that felt like I was gaming the system a little bit, and the multiple profiles was a point of concern to me.